# Adding channel numbers to an M3U playlist

Tags: bash

I need to add channel numbers to an M3U playlist file.  These channel numbers are passed to the script by an interactive prompt.  This all works 90%.

The idea is that the script will move through the M3U line by line and add in a particular place.  Unfortunately it does all the lines but adds each channel number to each line instead of one channel number per line, im a bit lost having got this far, any ideas?

```bash
#!/bin/bash
LISTA="test.m3u"
LINEA_INFO=0
IFS=$'\n'
(
  while read LINEA; do
    INFO=$(echo "$LINEA" | grep '^#EXTINF:')
    if [ "$LINEA_INFO" -eq 0 ] && [ -n "$INFO" ]; then
      LINEA_INFO=1
      CHANNELNAME=$(echo "$LINEA" | sed 's|.*,||')
      echo choose the channel number for $CHANNELNAME
      read varnumber < /dev/tty;
      echo you chose $varnumber for $CHANNELNAME
    fi
    if [ "$LINEA_INFO" -eq 1 ] && [ -z "$INFO" ]; then
      LINEA_INFO=0
      echo "$LINEA" | sed -i -e's/\#EXTINF:-1\>/& tvg-chno="'$varnumber'"/' $LISTA
   fi
 done < "$LISTA"
) 
echo "Done!"
```

[[example input file]](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ltd6rlwfm4lpbj/test.m3u?dl=0)

[example of the expected output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n4f25ghw6g12wce/correct.m3u?dl=0)

Comment: Could you please provide an example input-file and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the shell script should go through each line of the input m3u file and fill in the channel numbers that are requested interactively for each line. So, I suggest:

```
#!/bin/bash
InputList="$1"
OutputList="$2"

> "$OutputList"
while IFS= read -r Line; do
  if [[ "$Line" =~ ^#EXTINF: ]]; then
    echo "choose the channel number for $Line"
    read varnumber < /dev/tty
    echo "you chose $varnumber for $Line"
    Line="${Line%% *} tvg-chno=\"${varnumber}\" ${Line#* }"
  fi
  echo "$Line" >> "$OutputList"
done < "$InputList"
```

Invocation:

```
$ ./m3u_channels.sh test-1.m3u test-1-ch.m3u
```

It produces a file `test-1-ch.m3u` with the channel numbers inserted.

---

### How does it work?

The program is pretty much straight forward. It reads in the file given by `$InputList` line by line with the `while` loop. `read` stops at every line break (by default, as used here). If the line begins with `#EXTIF:`, the user is prompted, their input is stored in the variable `$varnumber` (copied from your program). Afterwards, the variable `$Line` is put together as:

1. `${Line%% *}`: Beginning of the string `$Line`to the first space.
2. A space, literally.
3. `tvg-chno=\"${varnumber}\"` the string with the channel number.
4. A space, literally.
5. `${Line#* }`: The string `$Line` from the first space.

Then, the content of the variable `$Line` is appended to the output file, be it modified or not.

Comment: This works perfectly thankyou so much, I need to add a few parts to the code so at to remove some unwanted parts on each line, im guessing this can all be done within the current while loop?

Comment: @stred you can put the content of the variable $Line in a way you want. The command `echo "$Line" >> "$OutputList"` appends the content of the variable whatever content it holds.